# URL Rewrite and 301 Permission not working properly

Tags: url, url-rewrite, 404

I am facing problem in url rewrite.

My problem is I want to redirect a page to `root/mods/myvapelife-mod.html` with 301 redirection but it is not happenning.

1. I have deleted old one url rewrite and created new url rewrite but I get a 404 error page not found.
2. I recreated old one same as old one here is its snap

[image: old url rewrite after recreated using custom]

It is working but problem is it does not redirect as 301.

3. Whenever I am changing to 301 permission for this then target url becomes `root/catalog/category/view/id/48` which I don't need. I need url like `root/mods/myvapelife-mod.html`.
4. I have tried like this

[image: i need this target ulr]

But it is resulting 404 ERROR Page Not Found.

Please help me fixing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Request Path = the path that the user is visiting (or in other words the broser is *requesting*).

Target Path = Magento's internal path with category and ID - the page (product, category or whatever whose content is *delivered*)

The sample from your first picture will most likely return a HTTP 200, since Magento redirects *internally* and acts as if the page with the requested path was actually there, you would not want to change the redirect status from anything than no (I guess it's database-managed). It behaves like not giving the `[R]`-flag in `.htaccess` at all.

To set up a "real" 301 rewrite, you'll have to have an *existing request path* for the URL to rewrite.

So you could 301 the `mods/myvapelife-mod.html` (request path) to `mods/myvapelife-mod-2016.html` (target path) where the target path is what the user eventually sees in his/her adress bar. But you would have to have `mods/myvapelife-mod.html` somewhere else to tell Magento which product or category to show when this URL is called.

But I am not quite sure why you have a "`root`" in you folder at all. Is that supposed to be part of the URI-string?

Comment: URL Rewrite Management not working after Re-indexed For Category Redirect https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/210130/57334